# How to parse an object from an element with multiple, same named sub elements. (SimpleXML Android)

Tags: android, xml, xml-parsing, simple-framework

I trying to parse some XML to objects (Android) and using the Simple XML library for it. I can parse some elements with sub elements or lists in it but when an element has multiple sub elements with the same tag name then i get an error:

Element 'Item' is already used with....

I understand that tags with the same name are an problem but every tag has another attribute so that can be used to solve that problem. I try-ed a lot but i cant get it done.

```
<Channel>
   <News>
        <Item kind="dunno">
                //An string with some info
        </Item>
        <Item kind="anotherOne">
                 //An string with some info
        </Item>
        <Item kind="Pfff">
                 //An string with some info
        </Item>
    </News>
</Channel>
```

I tryed the following:

```
@Root(name = "Channel")
public class Channel
    {
        @Elementlist(inline = true)
        private List<News> news;
    }


@Root(name = "News")
public class News
    {
        @Element(name = item)
        private String item;
    }
```

But this doesnt work becouse item alrealy used. I tryed to make it an list but doesnt work also. I tryed some more things but as i said, i cant get it done.

The thing i wanna have is that i have an Chanel object which contains one or more news object which contains one or more items. Sometimes there is only 1 items, sometimes there are more.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. Insead of

```
@Root(name = "Channel")
public class Channel
{
    @Elementlist(inline = true)
    private List<News> news;
}
```

I need to do the understanding instead.

```
@Root(name = "Channel")
public class Channel
{
    @Elementlist(name="News")
    private List<String> news;
}
```

The library automatically recognizes the items an add these to the list.The whole news class isn't necessary anymore.